# Reference Static Resource in Zip File

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I've been doing [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce):

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.file,'0.jpg')}
```

to reference from a visual force page a static resource inside a zip file, there are some files 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc. at the top level of the zip file but is beyond me why is not working (by this I mean, the image is not showing in the page). If someone can enlighten me about it, I would appreciate.

**Update**

I have a page construct as this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" cache="true" applyBodyTag="false" recordSetVar="contacts" extensions="Some_Ext">
    <head>
        <apex:styleSheet value="{!$Resource.style}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <apex:form>
            <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.resourcename, '0.jpg')}"/>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

**Note**

The problem was that the image was a .png not a .jpg as I was referencing in the VF Page.

**¡Be completely sure of the path and file EXTENSION when referencing a Static Resource!**

Comment: Are you 100% sure the files are in the top of the zip. I'm talking about situation where for resource "test" the archiving program created a folder "test" within the zip so you have to go `{!URLFOR($Resource.test,'test/0.jpg')}`

Comment: 100% sure. Actually tried with several paths as 'folder/img.jp', '/folder/img.jp', 'img.jp', '/img.jp', and so on. @eyescream

Comment: your body tag is not closed fine so its throwing errors( hopefully u have it right in the page) I copy paste your code and the image renders with no issue. Unless the 0.jpg is not 0 and it is a character o i would be surprised why the image is not loading as you are.

Comment: Its fine in my page. Just fix the typo, its 0 as in the number 0. @rao

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Any chance you can upload the zip (can contain just this 1 offending image) somewhere? Dropbox maybe? Does the browser's JS console report any errors like 404 file not found?

Comment: Your `URLFOR` syntax is correct, which means that your zip file structure is the issue. When you view the source markup for your page and click on the URL which was generated for that image, what do you get? A blank white page? Can you post the URL from your generated page markup?

Comment: A page with the "?" symbol, and the link when I right click - Open Image in new tab is: https://c.na10.visual.force.com/resource/1400709144000/resourcename/0.jpg @MarkPond

Comment: Its not the image (I think), because it happens with all the images and they work fine when not in a zip file. @eyescream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this documentation

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm

> To reference a file in an archive, use the URLFOR function. Specify
>   the static resource name that you provided when you uploaded the
>   archive with the first parameter, and the path to the desired file
>   within the archive with the second. For example:

```
 url="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestZip,
                  'images/Bluehills.jpg')}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

(OR) 
if 1 is too confusing save the CSS/ JS/ Image or be it anything as a seperate static resource and reference it in VF page as

```
URLFOR($Resource.file_image)
URLFOR($Resource.file_CSS)
URLFOR($Resource.file_image)
```

I usually prefer the second method since I have never been comfortable with zip file and extending the path.

**Update:**

My ZIP file content:

[image]

The page saves even though u do not have the closing } bracket, check if you have formed the image tag and closed the { and } for the URLFOR function.

Make sure the syntax is correct for the image tag as well as the URLFOR.

[image]

```
<apex:page >
<apex:form >
<apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tezip, 'te.jpg')}" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My output was :

![enter image description here][3]

---

***UPDATE 2:***

> YOUR CODE IN MY ORG :D:

---

[image]

Comment: Yeah, done that. Still not working. The second method works fine, but the idea is not to have so many resources.

Comment: @jose what is not working is the page not loading/ breaking/ not showing what you expect to see? can you paste your page and what you are trying

Comment: Is not showing the image, as if the path was incorrect.

Comment: can you try the path 2 where you save the image as a seperate static resource and reference it in a VF page since it s hard to say how the zip file is created etc.

Comment: Yes, right now I'm doing it like that and works but really want to know why the other option is not working.

Comment: Wow, great help. I just updated my question. I'm doing everything exactly as you, so I guess it must be something of the apex:page parameters I HAVE to use.

Comment: When you upload your zip file, the MIME Type in static resources page is 'application/zip'? 'tezip' is just the Static Resource name, right?

Comment: it says MIME Type application/octet-stream but i think application/zip is also a valid MIME http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type. Have you set the cache to be public?

Comment: Yes, is public.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14662/discussion-between-rao-and-jose).

Answer (score 2):

Here is something else you may wish to try:

Go to the static resource 'Detail' page via the Salesforce menu and copy the link address from the 'View file' link into the address bar of your browser. The link should look something like:

```
https://XXX.salesforce.com/resource/1000640032000/myResource
```

If you were to go to this address then your browser would just download the resource, however you can experiment by appending to the url to get at files within the ZIP file. For example I can get to:

```
https://XXX.salesforce.com/resource/1000640032000/myResource/myApp/application.js
```

This renders application.js in my browser without needing to download any zip file. I find this a much quicker way to figure out the correct relative paths within my static resources.

In terms of finding the correct relative path (i.e. the second parameter to URLFOR) I would suggest downloading the static resource by clicking 'View file' on the static resource detail page and unzip the downloaded resource. Lets say that unzipping this results in a folder called "myResource" that contains a single file called "myImg.jpg", then I believe that the path should be:

```
myResource/myImg.jpg
```

And hence in your Visualforce page you would use:

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.myResource,'myResource/myImg.jpg')}
```

This is a bit of a stab in the dark. I can only hope that it might help :-)

Comment: Also, I realise that some of the things I have mentioned have sort of already been mentioned in earlier comments.

Comment: When I downloaded it, it was just a folder with the Static Resource name (NOT ZIP, didn't have to unzip) and the files in it.

Comment: Interesting. A couple of questions, I presume it was definitely a ZIP file when you uploaded it? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes it was a zip, safari. Any how, found the problem - Check my question note.